# How do I monitor opened files of a process in realtime?

Tags: process, open-files, lsof, audit

I know I can view the open files of a process using `lsof` *at that moment in time* on my Linux machine. However, a process can open, alter and close a file so quickly that I won't be able to see it when monitoring it using standard shell scripting (e.g. `watch`) as explained in ["monitor open process files on linux (real-time)"](https://serverfault.com/questions/219323/monitor-open-process-files-on-linux-real-time).

So, I think I'm looking for a simple way of auditing a process and see what it has done over the time passed. It would be great if it's also possible to see what network connections it (tried to) make and to have the audit start before the process got time to run without the audit being started.

Ideally, I would like to do this:

```
sh $ audit-lsof /path/to/executable
4530.848254 OPEN  read  /etc/myconfig
4530.848260 OPEN  write /var/log/mylog.log
4540.345986 OPEN  read  /home/gert/.ssh/id_rsa          <-- suspicious
4540.650345 OPEN  socket TCP ::1:34895 -> 1.2.3.4:80    |
[...]
4541.023485 CLOSE       /home/gert/.ssh/id_rsa          <-- would have missed
4541.023485 CLOSE socket TCP ::1:34895 -> 1.2.3.4:80    |   this when polling
```

Would this be possible using `strace` and some flags to not see every system call?

Comment: [Continuously monitor files opened/accessed by a process](https://superuser.com/q/348738/241386)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Running it with

```
strace -e trace=open,openat,close,read,write,connect,accept your-command-here
```

would probably be sufficient.

You'll need to use the `-o` option to put strace's output somewhere other than the console, if the process can print to stderr. If your process forks, you'll also need `-f` or `-ff`.

Oh, and you might want `-t` as well, so you can see *when* the calls happened.

---

Note, you may need to tweak the function call list depending on what your process does - I needed to add `getdents` for example, to get better sample using `ls`:

```
$ strace -t -e trace=open,openat,close,read,getdents,write,connect,accept ls >/dev/null
...
09:34:48 open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
09:34:48 close(3)                       = 0
09:34:48 open("/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
09:34:48 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@V\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
09:34:48 close(3)                       = 0
...
09:34:48 open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY) = 3
09:34:48 read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tb"..., 1024) = 366
09:34:48 read(3, "", 1024)              = 0
09:34:48 close(3)                       = 0
09:34:48 open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
09:34:48 close(3)                       = 0
09:34:48 open(".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
09:34:48 getdents(3, /* 5 entries */, 32768) = 144
09:34:48 getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768) = 0
09:34:48 close(3)                       = 0
09:34:48 write(1, "file-A\nfile-B\nfile-C\n", 21) = 21
09:34:48 close(1)                       = 0
09:34:48 close(2)                       = 0
```

Comment: That's getting into the right direction, thanks! Would like a more user friendly output, but it does the job. I might take the time to write a tool with a more top-like interface for this. I was hoping an ncurses-based or 'top'-like tool would exist to inspect the binary's actions real-time.

Comment: How would you like it to look? It's probably possible to munge the strace output into something friendlier.

Comment: you definitely want to use `-o` to push the output to file(s). Then you can run `tail -F strace.output` in another terminal to get "live" update.

Comment: You can also attach `strace` to a running process with the `-p PID` option.

Comment: Add `-y` to "[p]rint paths associated with file descriptor arguments"

Comment: Don't forget **`openat`** and such!

Comment: If you want to see the paths of files opened, instead of just file numbers, see: https://serverfault.com/a/727647/104579