# How to monitor all file writes and reads initiated by a particular application?

Tags: files, process, monitoring

How can I monitor in real time, which files an application reads and writes to while it is running? In my particular case I want to monitor korganizer.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58887/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13555/117549

Comment: Did you do any kind of searching?

Comment: Those answers are quite old, I think it might be worth reopening this as strace can have side-effects to the process it's tracing and nowadays there are kernel-based tools like `ftrace`, `perf`or `systemtap` that can achieve that without affecting the app. I would upvote this if the answer gets updated to specifically state this is to monitor reads/writes under Linux and without using strace.

Answer (score 1):

So many ways, see the `man` pages for each of these:

Start the program under `strace`, and use `strace` options to only see the file operations you care about.

Download the source for `installwatch`, and adapt.

Repeated `lsof  -c korganizer`.