# How to find all the unclosed files of a process?

Tags: files, process, strace, open-files, trace

I'm trying to debug if my app keeps opened files somewhere in the code. I thought of using `strace` for that but all of the previous topics (like this [one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58887/how-do-i-monitor-opened-files-of-a-process-in-realtime)) were talking about only opened files. While this information is useful, I'm interested in files that were unclosed by the process and it's forks (for understandable reasons). How it can be done?

Comment: What about `lsof`?

Comment: Possibly looking in `/proc/$pid/fd`?